# Print something if ip address exists in file [ php ]

Tags: php

I have some php script that must find if ip address of user exist in txt file and print some text if it's not exist, do nothing.

So i do like this, but something is wrong and i don't know what. Please help. Thank you for help.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];}
else {$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];}

$lines = file('http://example.com/ip.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
$search_array = array($ip);
    if (array_key_exists($ip,$search_array)){ echo "Hello"; }
    /*else{ echo "not hello";}*/
}

 ?>
```

ip.txt have lines like this:

178.211.105.33

278.211.115.56

378.451.105.21

271.511.305.01

Comment: Why the remote file? Empty lines in there? CRLF perhaps? Why `array_key_exists`? Why not use `in_array` right away? What other steps have you taken to debug this?

Comment: *something is wrong* - what is wrong?

Comment: @splash58... nothing happend that's wrong, but must print text

Comment: @mario even if file in root directory, nothing happend.. No file has no empty lines... i use fopen and else.. but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find and fix my error..

in line

```
$search_array = array($ip); //-- that was error - $ip
if (array_key_exists($ip, $search_array)){ echo "Hello"; }  
//-- that was error - "array_key_exists"

 $search_array = array($line); //-- error fixed by this
 if (in_array($ip, $search_array)){ echo "Hello"; } 
 //-- thanx to @mario for using "in_array" against "array_key_exists"
```

Answer (score 1):

This already gets you an array:

```
$lines = file('http://example.com/ip.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

There's no need to loop over it.
You can just use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) right away:

```
$found = in_array($ip, $lines);
```

You might want to use `preg_grep()` if there's any formatting or linebreak variance in the file however.